# Optimization of powershell script

Tags: powershell, optimization, dll, compare, compareobject

I am comparing 2 DLL files based on name, size, last write time and version using the following script. These files are stored on a remote server. My script is working fine but it is taking too long. Is there a way to optimize my script?

```
function dll_compare {
    param($path1,$path2) 

    $first = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Filter *.dll
    $second =  Get-ChildItem -Path $path2 -Filter *.dll

    $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime, VersionInfo -PassThru  | Select Name, Length, LastWriteTime, sideindicator,@{n="VersionInfo";e= { $_.VersionInfo.Productversion }}
    $diff
}
```

Comment: 1. `Compare-DLL` would be a better choice according to naming conventions (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882537/what-is-the-naming-convention-for-powershell-functions-with-regard-to-upper-lowe). 2. How many files can there be in each variable ?

Comment: You are running the script locally referencing remote paths? Invoke-Command might be a good start in order to run this on the remote machine.

Comment: Seconded. 
There can by any number of files ranging from 1 to 100 @sodawillow
The paths are remote Matt.

Comment: Did you try with `Invoke-Command -computerName "ServerName"` and using local paths in the `scriptBlock` as advised by Matt ? That sure should speed up the process.

Comment: I did and it worked!
Thank you